# Grails 2.3.6 plugin can't find jcenter?

Tags: maven, grails, dependency-management, jcenter

I have a Grails 2.3.6 plugin with the following `BuildConfig`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }

    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'

    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo "https://myartifactory01/artifactory/my-snapshots"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run the following build invocation:

```
grails clean package-plugin create-pom fizzbuzz
```

I get:

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.6
Error |
There was an error loading the BuildConfig: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigSlurper$_parse_closure5.jcenter() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: clone(), getMc(), iterator(), println(), every(), println() (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

**Why?**